# Generate links with data without database?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can someone help me?
I have a text box on my index,and for example if i input "text1" into it and hit the submit button it will be redirected on a new page where the "text1" will be displayed.
But everytime i input new text on my index textbox i want to generate new unique URL and remember the data inserted into text box from index.
Is there a way to do this without mysql database?
Think that every time my users access that unique URL to have that "text1" inserted from index.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

hey it kind of sounds like you want to use the $_GET function

so imagine like you want the name to be Negru you can do something like

```
<?php echo $_GET['name'] ?>
  index.php?name="namehere"
```

you can change the name and it will always display the name you give

Answer (score 0):

put your data in query strings. I don't know how to do that in PHP though.

The address will look like `www.yourwebsite.com/new-page?data-you-want-to-pass="value"`

Comment: Yes,this will work. But how can i do this?

Comment: @NegruGabriel I will leave it to someone who knows php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<form method="post" action="send.php" id="idOfForm">
  <textarea name="msg" id="msg"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
<button onclick="doPreview();">Preview</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doPreview()
    {
        form=document.getElementById('idOfForm');
        form.target='_blank';
        form.action='preview.php';
        form.submit();
        form.action='send.php';
        form.target='';
    }
</script>
```